# Average or max of strings

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Say I had the following values

```
{ "Great", "Good", "Ok", "Poor", "Sucks" }
```

I had a list of questions with those as the answers.

How would I calc this with linq to objects? For integers, I would do:

`var q = (from g in questions select g.Answer).Max();` or `select g.Answer).Avg();`

How would I approach this with strings, **not integers**?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. For example, what would be the average of `"Great"` and `"Good"`? Can't you just convert the strings to numbers, perform the computation and then convert back?

Comment: What would you expect Max or Average to return? Longest string length (or average)? Some other quantification (i.e. Great = 5, Sucks = 0)?

Comment: You need to define what values each word has.

Comment: No, just want the most choosen answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you told me is "Great" > "Sucks" or "Great" < "Sucks" ?

I think it depends on independent business ,  If I were you , I would define a enum to manage it . like below

```
Enum Sample
{
   Great = 1, 
   Good, 
   Ok,
   Poor, 
   Sucks 
}
```

Then you can compare it in your code.

And , if you just need compare your list by its index , you can try this way.

```
        var data = new List<string>(){ "Great", "Good", "Ok", "Poor", "Sucks" };
        var result = data.Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v });
```

then you can complete it with your own logic.

**UPDATE**

You can try this way , if you just need get the max length string.

```
        var answers = new string[]{ "Grt", "Grt", "Good", "Poor" };
        var result = answers.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Length >= b.Length ? a : b);
```

**Get the most frequent value**

```
        var answers = new string[]{ "Grt", "Grt", "Good", "Poor" };
        var result = answers.GroupBy(q => q)
                                .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
                                .Select(g => g.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Get the most frequent value for multiple values**

```
        var answers = new string[] { "Grt", "Grt", "Good", "Good","kk"};
        var results = from p in answers
                      group p by p into g
                      let max = answers.GroupBy(p => p).Select(p => p.Count()).Max()
                      where g.Count() == max
                      select g.Key;
```

Comment: Enum can be cast as int to compare them.
var a = Sample.Great;
var b = Sample.Good;
if ((int)a < (int)b) { ... }

Comment: @Zyo: You can also compare enums directly: `if (Sample.Great < Sample.Good)`.

Comment: If you have multiple answers that occur an equal number of times (e.g. change your array to `var answers = new string[] { "Grt", "Grt", "Good", "Poor", "Good" };`), your code will only return one (the first) of those answers.  See my answer for how to handle this.

Comment: @BACON Yes , but it is depends the business right ? if you want to get the multiple values you just change the firstordefault() to  ToList()  , and get the values later...here is just get the only one.

Answer (score 3):

You could put your "answer" values into a Dictionary, along with their values:

```
var answers = new Dictionary<string, int>();
answers.Add("Great", 5);
answers.Add("Good", 4);
answers.Add("Ok", 3);
answers.Add("Poor", 2);
answers.Add("Sucks", 1);

var q = questions.Select(q => answers[q.Answer]).Max();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a function (or even just a dictionary) that maps the string values to integers and use the query in your question. I.e. call this function with `g.answer` as input.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var answerKinds = new[] { "Great", "Good", "Ok", "Poor", "Sucks" };
  var answerKindRanks = answerKinds.Select((kind, rank) => new { kind, rank })
   .ToDictionary(pair => pair.kind, pair => pair.rank);

  var questions = new[]
  {
    new{Q = "bla-bla", Answer = "Great"},
    new{Q = "bla-bla", Answer = "Sucks"},
    new{Q = "bla-bla", Answer = "Poor"},
  };
  var averageAnswer = answerKinds[(int)Math.Round(questions.Select(g => answerKindRanks[g.Answer]).Average())];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] answers = new[] { "Great", "Good", "Ok", "Poor", "Sucks" };

var coolestAnswer = answers[questions.Select(q => Array.IndexOf(answers, q.Answer)).Min()];
var averageAnswer = answers[(int)questions.Select(q => Array.IndexOf(answers, q.Answer)).Average()];
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the question (and subsequent comment) is that, in a set of responses to questions, you want to find which answer was the most common.  Try the following:

```
class Question
{
    public string Answer;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var questions = new Question[] {
        new Question() { Answer = "Great" },
        new Question() { Answer = "Good" },
        new Question() { Answer = "Poor" },
        new Question() { Answer = "Good" },
        new Question() { Answer = "Great" },
        new Question() { Answer = "Sucks" }
    };
    var questionGroupsWithCount = from question in questions
                                  group question by question.Answer into questionGroup
                                  select new {
                                      QuestionCount = questionGroup.Count(),
                                      QuestionGroup = questionGroup
                                  };
    var mostCommonAnswerCount = questionGroupsWithCount.Max(item => item.QuestionCount);
    var mostCommonAnswers = from item in questionGroupsWithCount
                            where item.QuestionCount == mostCommonAnswerCount
                            select item.QuestionGroup.Key;

    foreach (var answer in mostCommonAnswers)
        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" was chosen {1:N0} time(s).", answer, mostCommonAnswerCount);
}
```

Here's what it's doing:

- The collection of `Question`s are grouped together by identical `Answer`s.  The number of `Question`s in each of those groups is computed and stored in an anonymous type alongside the group itself.
- The size of the largest groups are retrieved.
- The `Key`s, which are the values of the `Answer` fields, of the groups with the largest size are retrieved.

Note that it's possible to have multiple answers that are the "most common", and this correctly handles that.  The above code prints:

```
"Great" was chosen 2 time(s).
"Good" was chosen 2 time(s).
```

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer myself in another thread.

```
string[] answers = { "Great", "Great", "Good", "Poor" };
string text = answers.AsQueryable().Select(x => x).
    OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Since `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, `x.Count()` is actually returning the length in characters of `x`.  So, this just returns the longest `string` in `answers`.  Change the lengths of the `string`s and you'll see you get different results.

Comment: Your code returns `"Great"` because that is the longest `string` in `answers`, not because it is the most common `string` in `answers`.  Change your array to `string[] answers = { "Great", "Great", "Good", "Poor!!" };` and you'll see that your code then returns `"Poor!!"` (because `"Poor!!"` is six characters long), even though there is one occurrence of `"Poor!!"` and two occurrences of `"Great"`.  On a side note, the calls to `AsQueryable()` and `Select()` don't affect the result of that query and can be removed.

Comment: if your list is var answers = new string[]{ "Grt", "Grt", "Good", "Poor" };  what you want to get ? you want to get the most frequent value right ?

Comment: See my updated answer , and I get the most frequent value by group